# Email signature - align elements

Tags: html, css, html-table

I am trying to code an email signature for the first time. I have a problem to center vertically elements in one of my `tr` tags. I can't use `flex` and I am not sure how should I do it. As you can see the :idea: icon is not in the center verticaly

```html
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="width: 100%; max-width: 600px;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto; padding: 20px; border: none; box-shadow:
        none;font-family:'Trebuchet MS', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
        color: #1D1D1B; display: table;">

  <tr>
    <td colspan="3" width="100%" style="background-color:#CB444E; padding: 20px 34px; display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle;">
      <img src="https://www.flaticon.com/svg/vstatic/svg/3176/3176276.svg?token=exp=1612785759~hmac=066a03b72474de481ab5b4bca68a9a5d" alt="" style="width: 20px;">
      <span style="color: #fff; font-size:10px ;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</span>
      <button style="background-color: #fff; border: none; border-radius: 45px; width: 162px;height: 32px;"><a
                        href=""
                        style="text-decoration: none; color: #CB444E; font-weight: bold; font-size: 10px;">Lorem ipsum ipsu</a></button>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: According to SO guidelines you cannot ask 2 questions in one, please consider creating a new question for moving your button to right if neccessary :)

Answer (score 0):

For centering elements try `align-items`or `margin-left`

For moving right try with `float` or `margin-left`